# Php pages let connect only to android application

Tags: php, android, apache, .htaccess, security

I'm doing a secure application, for passing data from android to php and vice versa i use some php pages with echoing the data from php, the android read it as a string from URL, I'd like to give the access only to my android application, I don't want that the other people can go on that pages. I heard about .htaccess file or something on Apache. I've just thinked about some key or something similar but they can reach it from reverse engineering from application. How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387221/only-allow-access-to-php-file-through-application

Comment: thank you i've just read it, I thinked I could use something on server, that recognizes the device, like user-agent in .htaccess but something more secure